# How to Copy an Ext obj and display as HTML

Tags: extjs

I want to display an Ext form with its labels and values in a new modal window. I want the form to be read-only, so the user can print out the window. I can access the form and have the modal window appearing, but I can't seem to display the form in the modal window as it's an object.

Here's the window I have appearing when I click a button:

```
var printWindow = Ext.create("Ext.Window", {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'Print Window',
        cls: 'print',
        scrollable: true,
        closable: false,
        maximized: false,
        modal: false,
        moveable: false,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: mySample,
            height: 400,
            width:300
        }],
        dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'bottom',
                align: 'right',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'component',
                    flex: 1
                },{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    align: 'right',
                    text: 'Print This Window'
                }]
            }],
        tools: [{
            type: 'close',
            handler: function() {
                printWindow.close();
                htmlBody.removeCls('no-print');
                htmlBody.disabled = false;
            }
        },{
            type: 'print',
            tooltip:        'some tooltip info',
            handler: function() {
                print();
            }
        }]
    });
    printWindow.show();
```

Note - The HTML config option in the new panel is incorrect, I was using that for testing